# Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/razorpay/If) does not match path (com/razorpay/if.class)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/razorpay/If) does not match path (com/razorpay/if.class)**

Getting this error in my android studio project from 2 days. Earlier it was working fine with the library. When I include the razorpay library in my libs folder, this error is shown.

Already tried cleaning, rebuilding the project.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Hi. Were you able to fix this issue, i am facing a similar issue while enabling proguard on one of my imported library modules.Please help.?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your Gradle build system to 1.5.0-beta1

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta1'

Answer (score 0):

I changed my **gradle** version from

> 2.3.3

to

> 2.3.0

This solved my issue - perhaps your **gradle** version is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like one of your files has a capital I and one has a lowercase i. I just had a similar issue and I fixed it by going to that path and renaming it so it matches.

just go to /app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/razorpay/

and rename if.class to If.class